# Accordion Menu - How do I know that it will slide up or down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-events

I got an accordion menu (code below) and under the accordion menu I have a tag box. When accordion menu extends, I want to make my tag box go below the extended menu instead of extended menu covering up my tag box. So I change the value of CSS property "top" for my tag box after I count the # of sub-items being opened.

```
<div id="accordion"> 
  <h3>NOTEBOOKS</h3>

  <div class="sub_items" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
    <div onMouseOver="bgFadeIn(this)" onMouseOut="bgFadeOut(this)">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/casecrown_final/index.php/notebooks/black-slim.html">  
      <span>BLACK SLIM</span></a>
    </div>
    
    <div onMouseOver="bgFadeIn(this)" onMouseOut="bgFadeOut(this)">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/casecrown_final/index.php/notebooks/checkered-slim.html"> 
         <span>CHECKERED SLIM</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Another item</h3>
  <div class=sub_items" ......
.......
.....
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        
   var countTotalCategories = jQuery('#accordion > h3').size();
   var defaultHeight = countTotalCategories * 30;

   jQuery('#accordion> div').hide();  
    
   jQuery('#accordion> h3').click(function() {
      jQuery(this).next('div').slideToggle(400)
      .siblings('div:visible').slideUp(400);

      countProducts = jQuery(this).next('div').children('div:visible').size();
      var calculatedHeight= defaultHeight + 29 * countProducts;
            
      jQuery('.mini-product-tags').css('top' , calculatedHeight + 'px');
});
```

Now, how do I know that whether user is opening up a new menu to extend it...OR the user is closing the menu. I have no idea how to determine whether the user is closing up the menu so I can set the tag box value to the default when all accordion menu is closed. It seems like I only figure that out after the click event, I'm not sure when jQuery toggle event is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the prettiest way of doing it, but why not just find out whether the next element after your `<h3>` (i.e. your actual accordion container `<div>` tag) has `display: none` or not?

If your container is visible, then the click event will be to close it.  If the container is not visible, then the click event will be to open it.

So:

```
$(function() {

   ...

   $('#accordion> h3').click(function() {
      if ($(this).next('div').css("display") == "none")
      {
        // My accordion pane is closed
      }
      $(this).next('div').slideToggle(400)
      .siblings('div:visible').slideUp(400);
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you'll want to check for visibility. I would also consider using a different markup.

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/idoji)

the jquery:

```
// hide all that are not active
$("dd:not(#active)").hide(); 

// when the link is clicked (could make this an h3 if you wanted)
$("dt a").click(function(){ 
    // slide up the visible siblings
    $(this).parent().next().siblings("dd:visible").slideUp("fast"); 
    // slide down the next parent
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast"); 
    // remove the class of current from any other dt a
    $(".current").removeClass("current"); 
    // add the class of current to the anchor tag
    $(this).addClass("current"); 
    return false; 
});
```

the html:

```
<dl> 
<dt><a href="#">SOME ITEMS!</a></dt> 
<dd> 
<ul> 
  <li>Something</li> 
  <li>Something</li> 
  <li>Something</li> 
  <li>Something</li> 
  <li>Something</li> 
  <li>Something</li>           
</ul> 
</dd> 

<dt><a href="#">OTHER ITEMS!</a></dt> 
<dd> 
<ul> 
  <li>Other thing</li> 
  <li>Other thing</li> 
  <li>Other thing</li> 
  <li>Other thing</li> 
  <li>Other thing</li> 
  <li>Other thing</li>           
</ul> 
</dd> 

<dt><a href="#">ZOMG, MORE ITEMS!</a></dt> 
<dd> 
<ul> 
  <li>MORE things</li> 
  <li>MORE things</li> 
  <li>MORE things</li> 
  <li>MORE things</li> 
  <li>MORE things</li> 
  <li>MORE things</li>           
</ul> 
</dd>
```